# Eclipse unsupported major.minor version 52.0 [WIN10]

Tags: eclipse

So i'm setting up a Remote Administration Tool for my clients (i'm an app developer) and i'm new to this whole Eclipse thing.

So I have my project and it's ready to be Exported but it's giving me the error as stated in the title.

I've tried already installing JRE/DK 6,7,8 all putting them in every compilation setting but getting the same result in every single run.

Would be nice to get some help,
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled with greater version of Java and then you run with lesser version => you get unsupported major minor version error! simple as that!

this is already answered here : [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: So what version will I need to change to? I've already tried 6 and 7.

Comment: you need to compile with higer version. You have already tried JDK 8. so compile the project with JDK 8. **(not JRE)**. then give it a try

Comment: So in Preferences I was able to change the prefered installed JDK to 8 however it gave the same error, the properties and compile settings however can only go maximum 1.7, will this affect anything?

Comment: yes this will. you need to configure jdk 8 to your eclipse /netbeans. if you are using eclipse, change project facet setting to jdk 8 also and compiler version be 1.8

Comment: how do I edit the facets? thanks so much for the help currently :)

Comment: right click on the project, go to properties, on the left hand side you will see different options. choose project facet, select java version and click OK. U r welcome!

Comment: There's no "project facet" on the left side in Eclipse. Would you have skype so we can talk further into this? Thanks.

Comment: sure. my skype is vkotecha91

Comment: Ok I got it working, thanks so much for the help.
I downloaded the NEON version of Eclipse which had the facet as one of the options, highly appreciated! :)